# how would i create,edit, read,use table in ms access via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

how would i create edit  read use  table  in ms access via vb.net  please give me some help

Comment: not even close to a real question...

Answer (score 0):

You must create an ODBC connection in your VB script and then you can send SQL commands to the Access database.

[See here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/OdbcConnectionDemo.htm) for some code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ADO.Net and System.Data.OleDb (OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbDataAdapter, OleDbDataReader) and even DataSets.

See [this](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/msaccess.aspx) articlefor sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very clear tutorial to connect, retrieve, display, and update Ms Access database [here](http://pesona.mmu.edu.my/~ahmed.sameen/lab5_p/)..